# Current transformer response to step function DC voltage

Tags: transformer, dc, current-transformer, spike

I was playing with this [current transformer](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/cr-magnetics-inc/CR8410-1000/1045173?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKwA4wFoCMAGVB2ZA5AIiALoC%2BQA) as in the diagram (I've inserted the current transformer as an inductor) and noticed that for a DC step function the voltage is limited (in this example to roughly 3v) by the R2 resistor but I can't explain why; shouldn't a step function input on the primary cause a massive voltage spike on the secondary side? Why is this not the case?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjabkH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a primary spike voltage unless you open circuit the 7 amps you are applying. thus V=LdI/dt and dt would depend on the contact break capacitance, gap and arc.  The current rises to the limit determined by the resistance and risetime limited by the inductance/resistance ratio.

A current transformer here has a turns ratio of around 1:1000. Thus Current is reduced while voltage is increased. But the bandwidth rarely spans more than 2 decades unless exceptionally high permeability such as the nano-crystalline.

You must satisfy all the spec limits without exceeding the output voltage rating, so there are tradeoffs for choosing the load "burden resistor that converts the transformed current into voltage.

It is intended only for AC and in this case your link for the CR8410-1000-G is rated 20-1000 Hz.

If the primary side has a loop inductance typically around 1nH/mm or 1 uH/m and a 4 Ohm resistance the Lp/Rp=Tp time constant of 0.25 us is fast.

- a core using high permeability  with good mutual coupling and high inductance the low frequency response of 20 Hz will be limited by the Ls/510R=Ts secondary time constant for the step decay time.  Rise time appears should correlate with the spec for 2kHz BW. for *10~90%T=0.35/f-3dB BW*

**Te is the effective turns ratio is 1007** for your model in the link thus the voltage will follow the input current 28V/4R= 7A then / 1007 or ~ 7mA * 510 ohms= 3.57 V with the limitation on risetime due to winding capacitance and decay time due to L/R time constant.

I don't know the optimum burden R but consider the Vmax= 0.8Vrms.

The spec states "For best linearity, choose R such that V < 0.8 (max)"  ALthough you can get a lower frequency response with a higher R, but risk saturating the core if you exceed the voltage spec.

better reading material: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Current_transformer

Comment: thanks a ton for the answer!Could you explain what you mean in the first paragraph a bit simpler? I'm very rusty with this stuff

Comment: Also the second paragraph and on only apply for AC no? If i apply a step function why don't I see Vs = 1/1007d(flux)/dt, which i assume in a step up would be very high, in an ideal case infinitely high

Comment: And sorry if i wasnt clear i meant a voltage spike on the secondary side

Comment: current will not change that rapidly with alarge inductor in series with a step voltage. Explain your thought process. Were you assuming no burden R?

Comment: Hi! I'll admit I'm a little confused by this, My understanding is that for a transformer we have voltage driven on the secondary side by a change in current in the primary side, amperes law gets us from current to magnetic field and then faradays gets us back to a voltage, we say that the voltages and currents are related by the current ratio in AC as the derivative of a sin wave is a sin wave offset by 90deg. But when it comes to dc, or strictly speaking a step function this sin wave relationship is no longer true, and our new derivative is an impulse

Comment: what do you mean the inductor is in series? isnt it in a different circuit? On the primary side its just the wire, (which i know has some inductance but inst that inductance negligible?)

Comment: THere is only 1 inductor in your diagram, and the voltage is the derivative of the current V=Ldi/dt not the opposite so the current is not a spike but an integral to the step voltage

Comment: Sure but isnt the voltage across super high? Like here are the steps that happen in my mind: 1. The voltage V1 is stepped to 28v 2. this causes a 7 amp current that happens very quickly (this particular assumption is likely where i go wrong) 3. the voltage across the current transformer secondary goes up proportionally to a very high number

Comment: The current is multiplied by the resistance on the secondary

Comment: Also thank you for bearing with me on this i appreciate it

Comment: Ive just realized the confusion, I mean a step voltage on the primary side and a voltage spike on the secondary side

Comment: How much voltage is across the primary wire inside the core and primary resistor vs the secondary...afk